# Eevee renders gray/transparent image border on a simple plane

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Blender 3.5.1.
Add a Plane (1m by 1m).
Add an orthographic camera with orthographic scale set to 2 (should match plane exactly). Make sure camera is positioned from above onto the plane.
Assign a new material to the plane, add a noise texture and plug the noise color output directly to the shader's Surface Material output. No lights are in the scene. Render a Still Image with Eevee.

There is a one-pixel-wide (gray, sometimes transparent, seems to be random) border around the image. How do I get rid of this border (image is zoomed-in)?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Render Properties` tab, reduce the `Film > Filter Size`.
[image]

For illustration, if you increase the filter size the effect will become stronger:
[image]

Comment: Can't tell how much I would like to upvote this. This has saved me hours. Thank you very much.